# jQuery - Hide elements with left effect in certain point

Tags: jquery

Using this code

```
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
$('#hello').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
```

Text disappears when it arrives to the left of the screen, but  I'd like it to disappear with a difference of 20px, so the text would disappear before arriving to the left extrem of the screen.

Comment: to start with "SVN is dead; use https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui"

Comment: then what do i have to use?

Comment: Bottom of screen here http://jqueryui.com/

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

Seems like JQuery animate would really help you here:

```
 var NumberOfMilliseconds = 500;
 $('#hello').animate({left: '20px'}, NumberOfMilliseconds, function() {
    $(this).hide();
 });
```

This will move your element to 20px off from the left side of the screen (so long as it's absolutely positioned) and then the callback function will hide it at that point. JQuery has a great deal of built in functions, you should read through them sometime: http://api.jquery.com/